# Bootloader problems

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, bootloader

So I was making a bootloader and I can't get it to work. my compiler, gcc, gives an error when I insert my boot signature code via inline assembly:

```
__asm__("times 200h - 2 - ($-$$) db 0\n dw 0xAA55");
void main(){

}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Error: no such instruction: 'times 200h - 2 - ($-$$) db 0'
Error: no such instruction: 'dw 0xAA55'
```

what am I doing wrong?

by the way, my goal is to make my emulator QEMU find this file because of the boot signature and execute it, without using a asm file. so I only want to use C code, since I have a little bit more experience with that.

Comment: This is more or less an XY problem. It seems the question really is. How can I write a bootloader in _GCC_ with a boot signature in a particular place. The answer is you really can't. You can use a linker script to do it or you could create an assembly boot strap module that is used as the bootloader which then loads and then calls into the kernel and _C_ code. The other issue is that GCC/binutils generates 32-bit with a hack that allows it to run as 16-bit real mode code. This is ill advised unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Since GCC currently doesn't generate usable code that would run on processors earlier than a 386 it can be problematic. GCC doesn't have any notion of real mode segment addressing. I wrote some example code some time back. It is a simple 2 stage bootloader that uses bastardized real mode support. `int 13h` is used to read stage 2 from stage 1. It also initializes the BSS segment and sets up the stack and segment registers to allow the _C_ code to run as expected: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/ircasm/gccboot-2stage/

Comment: Just because you find code on the internet doesn't mean it is the best tool for the job. I use the example to show you have to jump through quite a few hoops just to get something basic working for real mode using GCC.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sadly though, I've given up on this project just because I can't find enough information about this subject online to understand what I'm doing.